# TeXShop key bindings with backticks

Tags: mac, texshop

I wish to create key bindings in TeXShop to replace accented characters I commonly use (è, à, é, ç, etc.) with their appropriate LaTeX entries.  In the Key Bindings Editor, I add the character as input (e.g., `è`) and the escaped LaTeX as output (e.g., `` \`e ``).

I am using OSX, which allows one to enter `è` by hitting `` <option> + ` `` and then hitting `e`. When I do this, however, the key binding only replaces the `e`; the `` ` `` persists, which leaves my final output as `` `\`e ``. I have tried to use `#INS#` and `#SEL#` to produce what I'm looking for, but to no avail. Even the key bindings that come with TeXShop (that are implemented similar to above) provide the same result for me.

One solution that might work is to code a backspace into the output, but I cannot determine how to do that (if it's even possible).

Comment: Why would you want ``\`e`` in the LaTeX file when it's possible to have `è`?

Comment: @egreg: I apologize; I was unclear in my intent. I want è in my final result, and therefore want it to be replaced by \\`e in my LaTeX code (just like many of the Key Bindings that already exist in TeXShop; I'm not sure why the escaped e's were not in there). I hope this clarifies my desire.

Comment: Is it really necessary to use their LaTeX entries if your are able to enter them the "usual" way? I guess Unicode encoding would be necessary, and I imagine there could be specific reasons not to use UTF.

Comment: @user11208: You're right; it's not vital, as it is quite easy to type \\`e. However, if that's the case, why are other key bindings (such as ö being replaced by \"o) pre-programmed into TeXShop?

Comment: From my point of view, it's partly a remain of the time before Unicode (but I'm perhaps totally wrong). It depends also of the keyboard layout: TeXShop is also designed for people using keyboards that have no direct access to accents.

Comment: I continue to not understanding: you *can* have `ò` directly in the document, so long as you add the proper call of `inputenc`.

Comment: Okay, thank you both. If the key bindings are a remnant of past times, then I think I understand.

I suppose what I'm getting at is that the inclusion of the original backtick seems to be a TeXShop bug; I would think it would be removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be sure that your TeXShop preferences show “Unicode (UTF-8)” in the encoding box

[image]

For greater safety, ensure that the line

```
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
```

is at the start of your files. You can get the string from the “Macros” menu, choosing the “Encoding” entry and then “Unicode (UTF-8)” in the window that appears.

Then a document such as

```
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel} % choose your own language

\begin{document}
à è é ì ò ù
\end{document}
```

will be typeset with the proper accented letters. No need of doing complicated macros or keyboard substitutions.