# Dead keys and TeXShop Key Bindings

Tags: keyboard

I have tried to create a shortcut for accented characters: á, é, í, ó, ú, in order to be replaced in the source code by: \'a, \'e, \'i, \'o, \'u, for this I have modified the autocompletion.plist file by adding the lines

[image]

But the result is a little strange: ´\'a, ´\'e, ´\'i, ´\'o, ´\'u.

Is it possible to correct this?

Comment: Why would you want to do this anyway? Use `inputenc` with the UTF-8 encoding (with pdfLaTeX) or use XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX and just enter them directly into your source.  (Make sure you change the default encoding in TeXShop to UTF-8.)

Comment: Oh thank you very much. In fact I can use the preamble of https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/139964/117400, but I believe that this generates more problems than solutions, especially if you work with shared files, which are used by several people with different operating systems and editors, or if you change computers yourself.

Comment: This should really cause you very few problems so long as everyone sets up their editor to use UTF-8.  If you have collaborators who are still using MacRoman or Latin1 encodings, you should introduce them to the 21st century... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, you can't create Keybindings for multi-stroke characters (i.e., those created with dead keys). (See TeXShop's Help->TeXShop Tips and Tricks.) But you can make Macros and assign them to Cmd-key shortcuts. Just be careful about the shortcuts you use so they don't interfere with those already assigned. I just ended up using the dead key versions, use utf-8 input and don't care.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found an indirect solution, or something similar. A keyboard can be created to satisfy this need. The idea is of Juan Luis Varona [here](http://www.unirioja.es/cu/jvarona/TeXkeylayout.html). He has created a couple of keyboards that can be installed on any Mac OS. With some modifications on this keyboards you can change the accent key by the characters \'. This new keyboard can be implemented in the keyboard preferences and it can be available with an icon (of our choice) in the input source bar.